# Passing a promise into ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs

So, I saw an example where they were passing an angualar deferred into ngRepeat and it worked fine. For some reason when I set up this example it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why? If you assign the data without the deferred it works fine i.e. `$scope.objects = [{id:1}...]`

Many thanks
**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/screenm0nkey/hh74a/3/)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <testlist/>

  <script src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
   var app = angular.module('app', []);

   app.factory('dataService', function ($q) {
     return {
       getData : function () {
         var deferred = $q.defer();
         setTimeout(function () {
           deferred.resolve([{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4}]);
         },0);
         return deferred.promise;
       }
     };
   });


   app.directive('testlist', ['dataService', function(dataService) {
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope : {},
        template: '<div ng-repeat="data in objects">{{inspect(data)}}{{data.id}}</div>',
        controller: function($scope) {
          $scope.objects = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4}];
          $scope.inspect = function (obj) {
            console.log(obj)
          }
        }
      }
    }]);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where did your saw such example? No such feature is documented [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat).

Comment: Hi Andrey, you can do it. See below. The example I saw working used an  old copy of angular where it worked out of the box whereas now you have to manually set $parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think you can use the promise objects directly, you should use the `then` callbacks as stated in the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q).

This means that your

```
$scope.objects = dataService.getData();
```

Should instead be something like

```
dataService.getData().then(function(data) {
    $scope.objects = data;
});
```

Otherwise, your `$scope.objects` will contain the promise object, and not the data you are passing to `resolve`.

See the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Raibaz/M98Wd/).

Comment: I'm pretty sure were passing the promise into ng-repeat. I'll dig out the example and check as it was a while back:)

Comment: Possibly related as well: http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/ especially the first comment, which says "Note that in 1.2 RC3 the promise unwrapping feature you mention in the last section has been removed". It has to be manually reactivated with `$parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true)`.

Comment: Re-updated the fiddle with `$parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true)`, it works as expected. Re-setting it to `false` behaves as in your question, while setting it to `true` allows to pass the promise objects to ng-repeat and have them parsed when they resolve.

Comment: +1 Raibaz, you're right. the example i saw on pluralsight used an old version of Angular. Thanks man. If you post that as an answer I will award it you:)

Comment: In [angular material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete) (and maybe other frameworks on top of angular), they support expressions (example: the [`md-items` attribute](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete)) which says "The results expression can be also a function, which returns the results synchronously or asynchronously (per Promise)", and whose working example shows the `md-items` correctly iterating over the (array) return value of a `deferred.promise`

Comment: I guess it must be special to the angular material framework , [because my modified version of Raibaz, which returns the promise result](http://jsfiddle.net/bvatmj98/) causes the error `Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!` That error is specifically explained on the [angular error link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig): "One common mistake is binding to a function which generates a new array every time it is called. For example:  `<div ng-repeat="user in getUsers()">...`" That's familiar.

Comment: And yet even if I return a consistent promise, still angular (alone) can't handle it; [this variation on the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvatmj98/1/) will return the same promise every time, but still angular can't process these results in an `ng-repeat`.