# Can't get object from list in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to show all the users in a list but this doesn't seem to work for me.

For now, I have the following:

```
<div ng-init="messageCtrl.getPatients()">
                        <tr ng-repeat="patient in messageCtrl.patientList">
                            <td>{{patient.username}}</td>
                            <td>{{patient.role}}</td>
                            {{messageCtrl.patientList[0].username}}
                        </tr>
                    </div>
```

And in the controller:

```
vm.getPatients = function(){
        userFactory.getPatientList($localStorage.user._id)
            .then(
                function success(response){
                    vm.patients= response.data;
                    vm.patientList = vm.patients.userList;
                },
                function(error, status, header, config){
                    vm.errorMsg = error;
                    vm.status = status;
                }
            )
    };
```

I think the problem is in the view because when I do {{messageCtrl.patientList[0].username}} the username shows up, but it doesn't show up when I try to do it in the ng-repeat, and I'm sure the data is in the patientList.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a promise into ngRepeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337666/passing-a-promise-into-ngrepeat)

Comment: Does `userFactory.getPatientList` use standard promises, or angular's $q promises?

Comment: @hege_hegedus yes I do use that!

Comment: I mean which one? $q and standard Promises work differently.

Answer (score 0):

## Set Scope in Ctrl

Inside your controller you should have

```
$scope.theArrayYouWantToRepeat = //whatevers in the array
```

Then in the html you should remove this line

```
<div ng-init="messageCtrl.getPatients()">
```

Your controller should be declared in your html with use ng-controller

## Scope

When you bind a variable or a function to scope you set it up for 2-way databinding. You should set up anything you need in the view with the $scope.

Controllers are supposed to add the business logic to your data before its presented in the view.

## Data Flow

For data flow in an angular app it might look a little something like this

1. database (probably mongodb or firebase)
2. API (this retrieves things like list of users etc.)
3. Factory or service that makes a $http call to the api
4. Controller where you call your factory and bind to $scope
5. View, where you show the data in your $scope with filters or loops etc.

## Conclusion

I hope this shows the process in a clear way.

Comment: Thank you, I almost got it working.
When I print {{list}} I get the users detail but not when I put it in an ng-repeat and this confuses me.. 
This is the output I get when I print {{list}}: 
[{"_id":"569262b056231a7f93c290cb","username":"patient1","password":"$2a$08$jeGVjynWWuggF4QoKscJm.Qo8DVyIpVPlpwSjnEXaaCzdetuA4IGa","role":"patient","__v":0,"treatmentList":[],"doctorList":["5692622e56231a7f93c290ca"],"userList":[]}]

Comment: must not be an array if it wont write them out